# Passing a relationship model through link-to helper? ember 2

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

Heyy!!

I'm having trouble passing a model to a route in ember cli. I'm making a simple app where posts have and author and a title. When you click the title you go to the post details and when you click the author you go to the author's profile. My problem is that I go to the respective user but when I refresh the page I get a n error in the author route. I have no idea why, I'm guessing it has to do with the model not being fetched again when I refresh since it passes the model using link-to helper

My code (client):

app/models/author.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true}),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  url: DS.attr('string')
});
```

app/models/post.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var attr= DS.attr;

export default DS.Model.extend({
 author: DS.belongsTo('author'),
 title: attr('string'),
 description: attr('string'),
 date: attr('date'),
 url:attr('string'),
});
```

app/routes/author.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController: function(controller, model) {
   model.reload();       
   controller.set('model', model);}
 });
```

app/templates/posts.hbs

```
    <div class="container" style="width:70%">
{{#each model as |post|}}
  <div class="well">

      <div class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" >
        <img class="media-object" src={{post.url}} style="width:200px;height:200px">
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h1>{{#link-to 'post' post}}{{post.title}}{{/link-to}}</h1>
         <h4>Posted by: {{#link-to 'author' post.author.id}}         {{post.author.name}}{{/link-to}} </h4>
          <p>{{post.description}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

My Code (server):

```
var authors=[];//list of authors
var profileRouter= express.Router();

profileRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.send({
'authors':authors
 });
});

profileRouter.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
res.send({
'author':  authors.find(function(user){
  return author.id==req.params.id
  // id: req.params.id,
})
});
});

app.use('/api/author', profileRouter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `link-to` is passing the model, which is not happening when the page is refreshed.  You need to define the model hook on the author route (which is not called when the model is passed) -

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('author', params.id);
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Please accept / upvote the answer if it was helpful.